# How to get a video to pause, play another video, and resume to the original video

Tags: javascript, html, video, event-handling

I have two videos, I want the first video to play for 10 seconds, pause, play the second video, and when the second video has stopped, return to playing the first video from where it left off. Kind of like an advert/commercial.

Currently I have two videos, that play sequentially, after the first one has completely ended. I know the solution is in the JavaScript event handler but the I can't seem to get it right.

HTML:

```
<div class="vidBox" id="contain">

  <video id="video1" class="vid" muted controls="true" height="300" width="500">
      <source src="http://jcath-drg.s3.amazonaws.com/BigBuck.m4v" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <video id="video2" class="vid2" autoplay muted controls="true" style="display:none;" height="300" width="500">
    <source src="http://jcath-drg.s3.amazonaws.com/BigBuck.m4v" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var vid = document.getElementById('video1');
vid.addEventListener("ended", hideVideo, false);

function hideVideo() {
    var vid = document.getElementById('video1');
    var vid2 = document.getElementById('video2');
    vid.removeEventListener("ended", hideVideo, false);
    vid.style.display='none';
    vid2.style.display='block';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, tested on chrome, safari, firefox: (I changed the second video to be able to tell if it is working, but you can set the one you want of course):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
</head>
<body> 

<div class="vidBox" id="contain">

  <video id="video1" class="vid" muted controls="true" height="300" width="500" autoplay>
      <source src="http://jcath-drg.s3.amazonaws.com/BigBuck.m4v" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <video id="video2" class="vid2" autoplay muted controls="true" style="display:none;" height="300" width="500">
    <source src="myVideo3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var vid = document.getElementById('video1');
vid.addEventListener("ended", hideVideo, false);

function hideVideo(event) {
    console.log("hideVideo");
    var vid = document.getElementById('video1');
    vid.pause();
    vid.style.display='none';
    vid.removeEventListener("ended", hideVideo, false);

    var vid2 = document.getElementById('video2');
    vid2.style.display='block';
    vid2.addEventListener("ended", hideVideo2, false);
    vid2.load();
}

function hideVideo2(event) {
    console.log("hideVideo2");
    var vid2 = document.getElementById('video2');
    vid2.style.display='none';

    var vid = document.getElementById('video1');
    vid.style.display='block';
    vid.play();
}

// start timer in milliseconds
setTimeout( hideVideo, 10000);

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This works well, thank you but there is a slight issue.. The second video begins playing at the setTimeout time is. I want the second video to start playing at 00:00 of its own video. Do you have a fix for this?

Comment: We can add the load() command to start from the beginning, see changes in the code above, Regards